# Flow Cadence: How to generate a random integer between two integer?

Tags: cadence, onflow-cadence

I tried unsafeRandom and this custom smart-contract without success:
https://github.com/justjoolz/PRNG/blob/master/cadence/contracts/PRNG.cdc

Comment: What issue did you have?

Comment: The usage example mentioned in the link doesn't work for me, I created a test script that imports that smart-contract, maybe I'm doing something wrong since I'm new to Cadence. I expected to find something simpler to generate a random number

Comment: Random numbers on chain are not straight forward. Easy to get wrong hence unsafeRandom being Cadence's only offering.

You can see how ChainMonsters used the PRNG contract here:

https://flow-view-source.com/mainnet/account/0x93615d25d14fa337/contract/ChainmonstersFoundation

Note that they are dual signing transactions with an Admin account to ensure transactions can't be reverted with a panic statement

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @j00lz, you can create a random between two integers (more specifically `UInt256` types) by using the `PRNG` contract found [here](https://flow-view-source.com/mainnet/account/0x93615d25d14fa337/contract/PRNG).

Essentially, you create a Generator resource based on a seed (or block height + integer), and call functions on that generator.

Here is a helpful example of how to use it (try it out [here](https://run.ecdao.org?code=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&network=mainnet&args=eyJtaW4iOjEwLCJtYXgiOjExfQ%3D%3D)):

```
import PRNG from 0x93615d25d14fa337

pub fun main(min: UInt256, max: UInt256): UInt256 {
  // create the generator resource
  let generator <- PRNG.createFrom(blockHeight: getCurrentBlock().height, uuid: 100)

  // call the range function to give you an integer between min and max
  let answer: UInt256 = generator.range(min, max)

  // destroy the generator resource
  destroy generator

  // return your answer
  return answer
}
```